# Some devices are not allowing the Settings app to launch in Flutter App(Device realme 8(Android version 11) and Huawei P30(Android version 9))

Tags: android, flutter

#### Device are Opening settings then immediately back causing app to crash

```
import 'package:permission_handler/permission_handler.dart' as p;

 try {
              await p.openAppSettings().onError((error, stackTrace) {
                showToast('Cannot open app settings on this platform');
                return false;
              });
            } catch (e) {
              showToast(e.toString());
            }
```

How to Open Setting Apps without Crashing.

Comment: What is the crash message? Can you post that?

Comment: you need to share the function openAppSettings() and log error from Crashing so people can help you

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.